# CSS: splitup fields in two columns

Tags: html, css, css-float, dokuwiki

I have some html-output, which i'd like to format better with css. **I have no influence on how the html is generated.**

I want to have two columns, depending on the class. I could use static positions for every field, but if a field is missing in data, there will be a gap.

This is what I search for. (as you see, the order is diffrent)

[image: desired result]

how to put the fields in a column, and deal with height dynamically?
help highly appreciated.

cheers endo

```html
<div class="inline dataplugin_entry person">
    <dl> 
        <dt class="id">ID<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="id">487</dd> 
        
        <dt class="wsid">wsID<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="wsid">2129</dd> 
        
        <dt class="aktiv">aktiv<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="aktiv">1</dd> 

        <dt class="nachname">Nachname<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="nachname">Smith</dd> 
        
        <dt class="vorname">Vorname<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="vorname">Bob</dd> 
        
        <dt class="kanton">Kanton<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="kanton">ZH</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: So basicall you need to display maximum 4 pairs of dt & dd in one column?

Comment: Another option would be to use some intermittend programm, that will rewrite your HTML by using some HTML Parser library (usig PHP, ASP, or else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't specified how many items you want to place in one column, I can advice on taking advantage of `column-count` [css3 property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-count). What it does is it will make browser to evenly distribute the content of element in exactly that number of columns. So in your case I assumed 2:

```
<div class="inline dataplugin_entry person">
    <dl> 
        <dt class="id">ID<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="id">487</dd> 

        <dt class="wsid">wsID<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="wsid">2129</dd> 

        <dt class="aktiv">aktiv<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="aktiv">1</dd> 

        <dt class="nachname">Nachname<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="nachname">Smith</dd> 

        <dt class="vorname">Vorname<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="vorname">Bob</dd> 

        <dt class="kanton">Kanton<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="kanton">ZH</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

CSS

```
dl {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
         column-count: 2;
}

dt { clear:left }
dt, dd { float:left }
```

Example on fiddle is here - [http://jsfiddle.net/dvbdkr28/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/dvbdkr28/1/)

Browser support pretty decent so all modern browsers supports it, plus IE10 and above. On mobiles support reaches as far as Android 2.3 and above.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I get on the first run

```css
.dataplugin_entry.person dt {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.dataplugin_entry.person dd {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.dataplugin_entry.person dt.aktiv,
.dataplugin_entry.person dt.kanton {
  float:right
}

.dataplugin_entry.person dd.aktiv,
.dataplugin_entry.person dd.kanton {
  float:right
}
```

```html
<div class="inline dataplugin_entry person">
    <dl> 
        <dt class="id">ID<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="id">487</dd> 
        
        <dt class="wsid">wsID<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="wsid">2129</dd> 
        
        <dt class="aktiv">aktiv<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="aktiv">1</dd> 

        <dt class="nachname">Nachname<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="nachname">Smith</dd> 
        
        <dt class="vorname">Vorname<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="vorname">Bob</dd> 
        
        <dt class="kanton">Kanton<span class="sep">: </span></dt>
        <dd class="kanton">ZH</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```